# Slack interactive message: POST response is not in json format

Tags: python, json, django, slack, slack-api

```
@csrf_exempt
def slack(request):
print("Testing slack")
if request.method == 'POST':
    print('request', str(request.body))
    webhook_url = 'xxxxxxxx'
    text = "Would you recommend it to customers?"
    request = unquote(unquote(request.body.decode(encoding='ascii')))
    print('url', request)
    slack_data = {
        "attachments": [
            {
                "fallback": "Would you recommend it to customers?",
                "title": request,
                "callback_id": "comic_1234_xyz",
                "color": "#3AA3E3",
                "attachment_type": "default",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "recommend",
                        "text": "Recommend",
                        "type": "button",
                        "value": "recommended"
                         }
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
    test = slack_data
    print('slack_data', type(slack_data))
    response = requests.post(
        webhook_url, data=json.dumps(test),
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    )
return HttpResponse("New comic book alert!")
```

In this str(request.body) I am getting output like: 
b'payload=%7B%22type%22%3A%22 interactive message%22%2C%

So I encoded it using unquote(unquote(request.body.decode(encoding='ascii'))) and I am able to get the payload in this format:

```
payload={ "here I got all details of POST message" }
```

How do I parse this in Json ?

Comment: That's not valid json (a string in {}) so you cannot parse it in json. Where does it come from? Why curly braces around a string? I assume the whole thing is a python string, so the only thing you can do is string manipulation (split on the = sign, remove the braces).

Comment: so if `request_body` is your string (don't call it `request`), then `request_body.split('=')[1].strip("\"\{\} ")` will give you the string after `payload=`

Comment: hi @dirkgroten I will send the complete payload Its in json format only

Comment: payload={  
   "type":"interactive_message",
   "actions":[  
      {  
         "name":"recommend",
         "type":"button",
         "value":"recommend"
      }
   ],
   "callback_id":"comic_1234_xyz",
   "team":{  
      "id":"TGFSRDHRU",
      "domain":"djangoslack"
   },
}   Payload is in this format. I need to parse it . How can I do It? I used json.loads but I am getting an error. Can you help please

Comment: @dirkgroten        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @daniel’s answer is correct. You’re seeing this error because your string starts with `payload=`

Comment: @dirkgroten sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to get `request.body` in the first place. It looks like you are posting standard form data, with a `payload` field which contains the JSON data. So just get that:

```
data = json.loads(request.POST['payload'])
```

Comment: ERROR:  json.loads(request.POST['payload'])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'POST'

Comment: You have redefined `request`. I have no idea why you have done that. As I said, there is no need to do anything with `request.body` anyway. Remove the whole line `request = unquote(unquote(request.body.decode(encoding='ascii')))`.

Comment: POST request is wsgi. In wsgi content  will be in request.body only right?

Comment: I have no idea what that comment means.